# PorterDuff with NinePatchDrawable

Tags: android, nine-patch, porter-duff

I am trying to use a 9 patch drawable to cut out a colored background using PorterDuff.
My Destination Image is a gray colored rectangle.
Source Image is a 9 patch balloon, which looks like this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMthi.png
```

The expected result is:
[balloon with grey inside, white background outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzaGL.png)

But I am getting 
[white inside balloon, black background outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHKKx.png)

My code for imageView:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //just some gray color background
    Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(R.color.light_gray, null);
    //this is a balloon in nine patch
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    //the result of this is white in balloon, black outside of the balloon.
    drawDirectlyOnCanvas(canvas, background, drawable);
    //this produces the expected result
    drawWithBitmap(canvas, background, drawable);
}

private void drawWithBitmap(Canvas passInCanvas, Drawable dest, Drawable src) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    dest.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    dest.draw(canvas);
    ((NinePatchDrawable)src).getPaint().setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    src.draw(canvas);
    passInCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}

private void drawDirectlyOnCanvas(Canvas passInCavas, Drawable dest, Drawable src) {
    dest.draw(passInCavas);
    ((NinePatchDrawable)src).getPaint().setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    src.draw(passInCavas);
}
```

I want to use drawDirectlyOnCanvas, because even though drawWithBitmap works, it is not as efficient.

Comment: You will loose your 9 patch-ability, if you attempt ANY colo operation on a 9 patch. Because the borders (which contain the 9 patch markers) will also be affected by the transformations.

Comment: @LonnieZamora thanks for your comment, I could not quite get what you mean. I still have my 9 patch-ability with the method drawWithBitmap, in that case, I am creating a new canvas that the 9 patch draws on. And it works that way. However, if I use the canvas that was passed into onDraw and draw directly on there, it doesn't work.

Comment: Every 9 patch must have a border with the **BLACK** markers of exactly **1px by 1px** on a transparent background. Or it won't work as expected.

Comment: @LonnieZamora, Yes, my 9 patch mask has that, and it still works with PorterDuff the same way would because drawWithBitmap method produces the correct result. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you touch the border, the 9 patch won't work anymore